# How to get navigation properties without Unique filtering data?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, include

I'm trying to use the Include method to return an entity with navigation properties. However, it is acting as a filter when no related entity is found in the related-alus table: meaning it will return no calculation at all. But if there is no related entity in related table, I would still want it to return a Calculation-entity.

If the fourth line is commented out, it will (in some cases) return no calculations at all. How can I write it to still return a Calculation entity (with navigation properties), even if the Container table has no related Alus-enitities?

```
Calculation calculation = this.GetAllAsEntity(
    cal => cal.UrlId == calculationUrlId, inc => inc
        .Include(calc => calc.Alus)
      //.Include(calc => calc.Container.Alus) --> makes calculation to return null in some cases?
        , true).SingleOrDefault();
```

The three entities are declared as followed:

```
public class Calculation : BaseEntity
{        
    [Required]
    public Guid UrlId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContainerId")]
    public virtual Container Container { get; set; }
}

public class Container : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual ICollection<Calculation> Calculations { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Alus> Alus { get; set; }
}

public class Alus : DomainEntity
{
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int? CalculationId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("CalculationId")]
    public virtual Calculation Calculation { get; set; }

    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    public int? ContainerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContainerId")]
    public virtual Container Container { get; set; }
}
```

I need the navigation properties so I can pass the Calculation entity to do another check elsewhere (but as above function returns null sometimes, its not possible):

```
return calculation.UrlId == calculation.Alus.Any(alus =>
                       (alus.CalculationId == calculation.Id
                           || alus.ContainerId == calculation.ContainerId));
```

Above LINQ statements produce these SQL statements:

[image]

Modelconfigurations:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Container>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Calculations)
    .WithOne(x => x.Container)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<Alus>()
    .HasCheckConstraint("CHK_CalculationIdOrContainerIdNOTNULL", "CalculationId IS NOT NULL OR ContainerId IS NOT NULL");
```

Comment: I'm very new to this. Do you mean the EF core version? It's 3.1.7

Comment: Add `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Information"` to the `Logging.LogLevel` section of your appsettings.Development.json, then look in ether the console window, or the output window of VS (remember you can change the output source at the top - it might not just be in "Debug")

Comment: Try to replace `.Include(calc => calc.Container.Alus)` with `.Include(calc => calc.Container).ThenInlucde(Container => Container.Alus)`

Comment: @CaiusJard I've added the produced SQL statements to my question.

Comment: @quain I've tested and compared them and they produce the exact same SQL statement. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Ok, so there's an inner join being generated there which, if there is no container for a calc, will mean that the calc will never work out. Tell us more about the relationship between calc and container (is it 1:1?) and show the OnModelConfiguring for these entities

Comment: There can be many calculations linked to a container. Every calculation will have a container. However, it is possible that not all containers have an Alus linked (Container.Alus can be null). I've added model configuration to my post (I think this is what you mean?)

Comment: @CaiusJard I think I just found out the tests that are failing just dont have a container attached, as is why the calculations return null. Thank you for the help.